# Why is my float object not callable? Literally copied this code from an example notebook and it's not working

Tags: python, input

```
alpha = 0.5;  # Contrast control

name = input('Your name: ')
print('Hello,', name)
#input = float(input("Enter alpha [0.0-1.0]: "))

# # We use the alpha provided by the user if it is between 0 and 1
# if( input >= 0, input <= 1 ):
#       alpha = input; 

betax = 1 - alpha; # Brightness control
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-b7a9133002e1> in <module>()
      3 alpha = 0.5;  # Contrast control
      4 
----> 5 name = input('Your name: ')
      6 print('Hello,', name)
      7 #input = float(input("Enter alpha [0.0-1.0]: "))

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

I have no idea why this doesn't work. I'm working in google colab btw. It's a really weird situation because the code on line 7 works once, but then when I run it again I get the same error. This happened multiple times so I tried copying an example code for inputting and I'm getting the same error, yet this exact same code works in other notebooks. Also the code on line 7 works without problems on my classmate's computer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Earlier you used `input` as a variable name and assigned a float to it.

Comment: this is the first time in my code that I used input

Comment: What does `print(input)` show?

Comment: You said it works once but fails the second time. So something LATER is redefining `input`, and it fails when you get back to this code again.

Comment: Search for `input =` somewhere in your code.

Comment: I renamed the variable in line 7 to uinput and its working today, though yesterday I tried the same thing and it wasn't working for me so im not sure if this is a temporary or permanent solution

Comment: Oops, I didn't even notice that commented line before. That's definitely the problem.